# Nothing shows up on the screen react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I didn't use react for a while and i had to upgrade react-router-dom to new version now it's not working. I think i changed everything i had to to upgrade. Nothing shows up on the screeen its something about path? I tried with "/" "" with or without exact.

```
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="" component={<p>XD</p>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `element` instead of `component`

```
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<p>XD</p>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom` version 6 gone are the `Route` component's `component`, and `render` and `children` function props, replaced by a single `element` prop that takes a `ReactElement` (*i.e. JSX literal*) as a value. In RRDv6 all routes/paths are now also ***always*** exactly matched, so there is no longer an `exact` prop either.

[<Routes> and <Route>](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

1. Switch to using the `element` prop to render route content.
2. Remove the `exact` prop, it is no longer necessary.

Code

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<p>XD</p>} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

To catch up on other changes from v5 see the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5).